# Finding out how many times a user is processed?

Tags: java, loops, methods

I'm having some trouble with a part of an assignment. I have to see how many times an employee is processed in my program, after the loop runs once it asks the user if they would like to process another. If they enter y for yes and then they enter n for end after the second employee calculation. I want it to say "Number of employees processed: 2". How could I do this?

```
package paytime;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        String firstName, lastName, choice;
        double hoursWorked, hourlyWage;
        boolean processAnotherEmployee = true;
        Employee one = new Employee();


        while(true)
        {
            if (processAnotherEmployee) 
            {
        System.out.print("Enter Y to process employee or any other key to end: ");
        choice = scn.next();
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {

        System.out.print("Enter employee number: ");
        int number = scn.nextInt();

        while (!one.findEmpNumber(number))
        {
            System.out.print("Invlaid, enter a proper employee number: ");
            number = scn.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
        firstName = scn.next();

        System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
        lastName = scn.next();

        System.out.print("Enter hours worked: ");
        hoursWorked = scn.nextDouble();

        while (hoursWorked < 0)
        {
            System.out.print("Negative hours not allowed. Enter hours worked: ");
            hoursWorked = scn.nextDouble();
        }

        System.out.print("Enter hourly wage: $");
        hourlyWage = scn.nextDouble();

        while (hourlyWage < 0 || hourlyWage > 100)
        {
            System.out.print("Negative wage is not allowed or wage entered is to high. Enter hourley wage: $");
            hourlyWage = scn.nextDouble();
        }
        double overtimeHours = hoursWorked - 40; 
        double overtimeWage = hourlyWage * 1.5;
        System.out.println(" ");

        if (hoursWorked <= 40.0)
        {
        System.out.println("Worker " + number + " Paycheck Information: ");
        System.out.println("Name is: " + firstName + " " + lastName);
        System.out.println("Weekly Pay is: " + one.callWeeklyPay(hoursWorked, hourlyWage));
        System.out.println("Income Taxes is: " + one.callIncomeTax());
        System.out.println("Net Pay is: " + one.callNetPay());
        }
        else if (hoursWorked > 40.0)
        {
        System.out.println("Worker " + number + " Paycheck Information: ");
        System.out.println("Name is: " + firstName + " " + lastName);
        System.out.println("Weekly Pay is: " + one.callWeeklyPay(hoursWorked, hourlyWage));
        System.out.println("Income Taxes is: " + one.callIncomeTax());
        System.out.println("Net Pay is: " + one.callNetPay());

        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.println("Worker " + number + " Overtime Calculation: ");
        System.out.println("Overtime Pay is: " + one.callOvertimePay(overtimeHours, overtimeWage, hourlyWage, hoursWorked));
        System.out.println("Overtime Income Tax is: " + one.callOvertimeTax());
        System.out.println("Overtime Net Pay is: " + one.callOvertimeNetPay());
        System.out.println("Total Net Pay is: " + one.callTotalNetPay());
        System.out.println(" ");
        }
        }
        else if (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
            {
                processAnotherEmployee = false;
                System.out.println("Total number of Employees processed: ");
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("End of program");
                break;
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
package paytime;

public class Employee {
    private int empNumbers [] = {101, 103, 106, 109, 110, 113, 116, 118, 120};
    public double weeklyPay, hoursWorked, hourlyWage, incomeTax, netPay, 
            overtimePay, overtimeHours, overtimeWage, overtimeIncomeTax, 
            overtimeNetPay, totalNetPay;

    public boolean findEmpNumber(int number)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int sub = 0; sub < empNumbers.length; sub++)
        {
            if (number == empNumbers[sub])
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

    private void calculateWeeklyPay(double hoursWorked, double hourlyWage) {
        if (hoursWorked > 40)
        {
            hoursWorked = 40;
            weeklyPay = hoursWorked * hourlyWage;
        }
        else
        {
            weeklyPay = hoursWorked * hourlyWage;
        }
    }

    public double callWeeklyPay(double hoursWorked, double hourlyWage) {
        calculateWeeklyPay(hoursWorked, hourlyWage);
        return weeklyPay;
    }

    private void calculateIncomeTax() {
        if (weeklyPay > 0.0 && weeklyPay <= 300.0)
        {
            incomeTax = weeklyPay * 0.10;
        }
        else if (weeklyPay > 300.1 && weeklyPay <= 400.0)
        {
            incomeTax = weeklyPay * 0.12;
        }
        else if (weeklyPay > 400.1 && weeklyPay <= 500.0)
        {
            incomeTax = weeklyPay * 0.15;
        }
        else if (weeklyPay > 500.1)
        {
            incomeTax = weeklyPay * 0.20;
        }
    }

    public double callIncomeTax() {
        calculateIncomeTax();
        return incomeTax;
    }

    private void calculateNetPay() {
        netPay = weeklyPay - incomeTax;
    }

    public double callNetPay() {
        calculateNetPay();
        return netPay;
    }

    private void calculateOvertimePay(double overtimeHours, double overtimeWage, double hourlyWage, double hoursWorked) {
        overtimePay = overtimeHours * overtimeWage;
    }

    public double callOvertimePay(double overtimeHours, double overtimeWage, double hourlyWage, double hoursWorked) {
        calculateOvertimePay(overtimeHours, overtimeWage, hourlyWage, hoursWorked);
        return overtimePay;
    }

    private void calculateOvertimeTax() {
        overtimeIncomeTax = overtimePay * 0.25;
    }

    public double callOvertimeTax() {
        calculateOvertimeTax();
        return overtimeIncomeTax;
    }

    private void calculateOvertimeNetPay() {
        overtimeNetPay = overtimePay - overtimeIncomeTax;
    }

    public double callOvertimeNetPay() {
        calculateOvertimeNetPay();
        return overtimeNetPay;
    }

    private void calculateTotalNetPay() {
        totalNetPay = netPay + overtimeNetPay;
    }

    public double callTotalNetPay() {
        calculateTotalNetPay();
        return totalNetPay;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply having "int employeesProcessed = 0;" outside of you while loop then add "employeesProcessed++;" directly after "if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))" so that each time your program is asked to process an employ you add 1 to your int that is keeping track of how many employees you have processed. Then you can add this variable onto the end of your printed string so it says "Total number of Employees processed: " + employeesProcessed.